# How do I safely run a Windows command through php code?

Tags: php

I would like to run a .exe file on the server through php.

currently the command line works with the following:

`build.exe C:\route\to\file\input\something.file -o output.file`

I'm running windows so I think I can use `exec()`

Is it as simple as `exec(build.exe C:\route\to\file\input\something.file -o output.file)`

Compliled it will be something like:

```
<?php
  $input
  $file_name
  $output
  exec(build.exe $input\$file_name -o $output)
?>
```

I'm rusty to php so suggestions/corrections are welcome.

Comment: You should probably refresh your knowledge of PHP first - the code you've written there isn't valid at all.

Comment: So, have you tested anything? That code won't compile. Yes, as per the manual you can use exec() or shell_exec(). As for "safety", it depends. Are you planning to allow any user input to be fed into the command? Are you thinking about permissions? It's a bit unclear what specifically you're asking about.

Comment: i guess it depends on what you mean by "safely" if you want to execute arbitrary commands (for example user input) then exec is not safe at all.

Comment: If you had access to the system, why run a compiler through PHP? This seems fishy. Have you looked at the [PHP exec() documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php)?